# Guild join date is showing as today's date when it isn't?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I created a profile command in my discord bot which returns detailed info. The "Server Join Date:" is incorrect.

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it? Thanks in advance

```
let member = message.mentions.members.first() || message.member,
        user = member.user;
```

Part of my embed:

```
"**Server join Date: **" + `${moment.utc(member.JoinedAt).format('DD/MM/YY')}` + "\n" +
```

I expected this to show the join date of the member, instead it shows today's date. I tried this with several users, they all joined the server at a different date.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You used:

```
"**Server join Date: **" + `${moment.utc(member.JoinedAt).format('DD/MM/YY')}` + "\n" +
```

But the mistake is, that the member property is called `.joinedAt` and not `.JoinedAt`!

The corrected version is:

```
"**Server join Date: **" + `${moment.utc(member.joinedAt).format('DD/MM/YY')}` + "\n" +
```

Comment: No worries, mistakes happen :) If it is correct please mark the answer as correct, this would be really kind! Thanks! @QueenInTheNorth